# Counter not increasing each time method is run

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically what the title says. I'm wanting it to pretty much to print the number of requests that have been sent after each request, however the counter just gets stuck at 1.

```
def send():
  while True:  
     total = 0
     req = requests.get(url)
     if req.status_code == 403:
         logging.info("Unable to fufill request!")
     else:
      pass
      total = total + 1
      logging.info(f"Request No. {total} sent")

for _ in range(int(amount)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=send)
    t.start()
```

Expected Output:

```
Request No. 1 sent
Request No. 2 sent
...
```

Received Output:

```
Request No. 1 sent
Request No. 1 sent
...
```

Comment: You have `total = 0` inside the loop, so it gets reset before each time you increment it.

Comment: It's inside the loop. You reset it every time.

Comment: Why do you have `pass` before `total = total + 1`? The only time you need `pass` is as a placeholder when you don't have any other code in a block.

Comment: This is a classic beginner mistake.

Comment: How are you planning on terminating the loop?

Comment: A more idiomatic loop, in any case, might be `for total in itertools.count(): ...`. This way, you don't need to initialize or increment `total` explicitly; it's all handled by the `count` iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting total in every iteration of your loop. Swap the first  two lines like this:

```
total = 0
while True:
```

edit:
You probably also want to use the `break` keyword to exit your loop `if req.status_code == 403`